# Enhanced MinVersion settings with Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

According to the documentation for the **Microsoft Framework 4.6.2** it is supported on:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 10

It is **not** supported on *Windows 8*.

**Inno Setup** supports a `MinVersion` property:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_winvernotes.htm

So how do I handle this in the setup? We can allow `6.1.7601` or greater but **not** allow `6.2.9200`?

Thanks.

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`GetWindowsVersion` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversion) from the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) to implement the custom restriction:

```pascal
function MakeVer(Major, Minor, Build: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := (Major shl 24) + (Minor shl 16) + Build;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  WindowsVersion: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := True;

  WindowsVersion := GetWindowsVersion;
  Log(Format('Windows Version: %x', [WindowsVersion]));
  if  (WindowsVersion <  MakeVer(6, 1, 7601)) or
     ((WindowsVersion >= MakeVer(6, 2, 0)) and (WindowsVersion < MakeVer(6, 3, 0))) then
  begin
    MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgWindowsVersionNotSupported), mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```